# Using EBS Volumes as storageclass for On-Premise Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

This is a very straightforward question. Can we use the aws-ebs storage class for a kubernetes cluster that is NOT in AWS. ( On-Premise ).

If at all, this is possible - how would we assign IAM roles to on premise nodes to do attachEBSVolumes, DescribeEBSVolumes etc.

Comment: You cannot attach aws ebs outside of aws vpc. Have you considered openebs?